# Colorblind-friendlier design

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility

I am not sure what color links are on the ELU site, but they are really hard for me to see as I am red-green colorblind. Could we either change them to a color with more contrast or add a bottom border?

http://www.chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/color-blind-accessible-figures/59189

Comment: I thought the underlining was a change that had already been decided—is it still coming? The [accepted answer to *Hyperlinks could be improved for colourblind individuals*](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/hyperlinks-could-be-improved-for-colourblind-individuals/1453#1453) from five years ago said that it would be implemented "in the next production build" but I don't know what/when that would be. Or maybe it was implemented, and then went away for some reason?

Comment: We used to have dotted-underline on links. See <[this search](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/search?q=links+dotted)>.

Comment: Recent question about the same issue: [Link style on the main site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9517). It's kind of discouraging that it hasn't gotten any response yet, but the SE team may be busy with other things.

Comment: Wow, embarrassed that I didn't do the same research I would before asking on the main site

Comment: It is unfortunately true that the difficulties of colorblind people are largely ignored by UI designers, even though 8 percent of the male population is color blind.  It's not such a big deal here, but I've seen it in medical applications, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks the problem is not where you see it. The problem is where you don't. ;) Sometimes I find out after years that there is supposed to be a helpful difference somewhere.

Comment: I find it very disheartening that this fix apparently was implemented and then *taken away*. That being the case, my guess is that it is not coming back. I have found a possible work-around, however. StackApps user Dennis created a [user script to make links underlined](http://stackapps.com/questions/3596/underlined-post-links). Unfortunately, I don't know how to run user apps, so I can't tell you whether this one works.

Comment: I brought up the link colours when the site theme was first implemented. Sadly nothing has changed.

Answer (score 6):

For those of us who are NOT colorblind, this the difference between normal and red-green colorblind link colors:

[image: original].......[image: colorblind]

(Image generated with [Vischeck](http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/vischeckImage.php))

There are three styles here:

**Visited link:** This answer here
**Unvisited link:** post
**Normal text:** also suggests

---

Even in full color, I think the links need more contrast.

---

I also did some research on achrive.org and found out that the link style was changed some time in January 2014:

[Beginning of January 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205133354/https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144052/difference-between-labyrinth-and-maze)
[End of January 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20150416150600/https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149035/meaning-of-parochial)

This change removed the persistent dotted underline, but, on hover, an underline appears. There must have been another change later on, since this doesn't happen now either.

Comment: I don't think I'd ever realized there was a difference between visited and not visited.  (But then I'm color blind.)