# "ELU updated site theme is ready for testing" is ready for voting, but still not visible

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **["ELU updated site theme is ready for testing"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11693/english-language-usages-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing)**

has been vigorously voted on. It turns out that currently it is

<s>25 down and 10 upvotes.</s>

34 down and 13 upvotes.

At a net of -21 votes, it is automatically *not* displayed on the Questions list.

**This meta-question is simply to make it more visible and easily reachable.**

It is also on the 'Featured on Meta' sidebar, which frankly I hardly ever pay attention to.

One might consider this a feature request to *not have negative net votes render a question hidden on Meta*.

Comment: Good idea. So let's vote for *this* question, to make it more visible.

Comment: It actually _is_ displayed on the Questions list: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/  or (of sorted by active)  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active . It's only suppressed from the front page.

Comment: I've asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315122/286574)  on Meta.SE about whether we can vote to **not** proceed with the planned roll-out.

Comment: @Lawrence - Lol. Good luck with that

Comment: @Richard Thanks :) . Do you like the new theme?

Comment: @Lawrence - No, it looks like garbage. But there's no use tilting against windmills

Comment: This is now a `HOT META POST`.

Comment: @JohnLawler and Mitch this is not news. The Hot Meta Post feature has been present for quite considerable time, I imagine its scope was to encourage visitors and newcomers to at least realise that meta existed thereby encouraging and fostering a sense of community and a "your views" count attitude. How else would newcomers to EL&U know of its existence, the newly installed icons are not self-explanatory by a long shot.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This is just tangential to your comment: I used to decry the SE / EL&U user interface, saying that all sorts of things got hidden away. Now I see what happens when they try to do something about it. I'm keeping the old interface for as long as they'll let me. (Actually - *speaking now to the SE staff* - since it's already a choice, why not keep it a choice? Those who choose the 'classic' look and feel will need to accept that it's not 'responsive'. That would be a reasonable trade-off.)

Comment: @JJJ The understanding would be that the *classic* front-end will never be maintained. It would be left like Area-51.SE and MO.SE as a legacy system.

Comment: @JJJ I guess that really does make the rest of us fuddy duddies. It’s been ... nice.

Comment: @JJJ fair call. :)

Comment: Today, if you click on the site's name in the hamburger on the right-hand  side, you are stuck on "Top Questions". You need to  know about the (*new*) left hamburger. How can I say this succinctly?? And funnily enough, **a meta post which has over 700 views is not listed in the "Top questions" page, which is absurd!**

Comment: Plus one here, so that there can be more DVs over there.

Comment: Ha! Your initial point about never before seeing the right nav meta posts has been used as a (deflect) defense weapon. https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8802/software-engineerings-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing#comment27449_8802 Maybe you could post a comment telling users what you did to overcome the non-visibility aspect. I think it absurd that SE  announcement meta posts, which have attracted nearly 1000 views, are in some way penalised because of the number of DVs they receive. More the reason they should be seen in default in my view.

Comment: @Mari-Lou edited to make this a feature request.

Comment: I think it's important to specify "official announcements by SE". I can imagine a normal user wanting to forget a bad post and being silently relieved that it is absent from the default view but this concession should be waived where announcements and posts by community leaders/managers/employees are concerned.

Comment: I think a feature request would be better as a separate question, where you can give reasons for the feature. Referencing this example, naturally; there may be others too.