# Graphical issue on the activity profile page

Tags: bug, design

Posting here because I don't have a profile in the right state to repro on other sites, but if it can be confirmed to be elsewhere please migrate to MSE.

The "track the next one" bar after earning a tracked badge overlaps the tab bar below it.

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: This question is a cross site duplicate of an [existing MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/323179). Also, it was already reported on ELU meta as an answer  to the [new design question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11758/191178), although it is unrelated to the new design. In any case, the devs are aware of it.