# It's hard to tell whether I've accepted an answer

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

When I'm looking at an answer to a question that I asked, I find it hard to tell whether I've accepted that answer.

[image: english-unchecked]
vs
[image: english-checked]

The difference is clear when they're placed next to each other, but not in isolation. The dark gray (#817f84) of the unchecked accept mark is more pronounced against the background than the lighter gray (#b5b5b5) of the inactive voting button, so if one doesn't a priori expect the check mark to be green, it might well mean that the check mark is active. Conversely, the green (#459718) is a bit washed out, so it isn't completely obvious that the check mark is active.

I haven't had this problem on other Stack Exchange sites. For example, on a beta site, it's
[image: beta-unchecked] 
vs
[image: beta-checked] 
The unchecked mark is the same shade of light gray as the inactive voting button, and the checked mark is a more pronounced green, so each is obvious in isolation.

In addition, there's a positioning glitch with the check mark on English.SE: it moves a few pixels towards the left when you mark an answer as accepted. Neither positioning of the check mark looks wrong to me in isolation, but it's weird that the position depends on the state.

Please tweak the colors of accept marks to make it easier to tell whether they're active or not. Less importantly, please settle on one vertical alignment.

Comment: Those ticks are on the "old" site design, which, excluding the topbar, has been around for at least five years. Do you have the same visibility problem if you switch to the new design/theme? Visit your profile, setting, preferences and enable the "beta test new theme" change. I also believe that all the beta sites are using the new theme.

Comment: Nobody on EL&U can modify the colour of elements, and nobody on the SE developing team will want to even consider doing this seeing as the new theme has been launched and will, sooner or later, be adopted by all 170+ sites

Comment: *Shh* … we don't want to spur them to change to the new theme more quickly. :P

Comment: The question is identical but there were no answers on the older question, so how can this question already have an answer when the only answer is the one I've supplied here. And it's up-to-date too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guess it would make more sense to close in the other direction. I can't do it, but feel free to ask a moderator to do it if you think it's important — as you say it'll soon be obsolete anyway.

Comment: Nothing is important online, everything is frivolous.

Answer (score 3):

On the old and once beloved (*sniff, sniff…*) theme, accepted answers look like this

[image]

On the new theme, which will take over, accepted answers will look like this

[image]

As anyone can tell, the green checkmark is super chunky and a bright vivid green.

I suggest that nothing can be done to modify the elements in the old theme because nothing will done. The OP can switch to the *beta test theme* via their [profile page](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/1165).

Comment: *Cf* "super chunky": it sort of looks like a brick.

Comment: "Once beloved" suggests that it no longer is. While SE staffers might feel that way about it, there are other people...