# Can we keep the previous green on English SE?

Tags: discussion, design

They are already quarrelling on meta about the accepted answer box getting a [darker green](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381858/why-has-the-green-accepted-answer-indicator-become-darker-on-all-the-sites). It looks especially disagreeable on ELU against the beige... I find it even annoying, but this is probably subjective.

I am just wondering, can ELU keep the old green, or MUST it comply to general changes done on SO?

Comment: I doubt we can ask the staff to customise colours or revert to the previous shade. I wonder what the dark green looks like on SO's black theme?

Comment: Urgh, the accepted answer box's a horrible pasty washed-out green with the dark theme. Much better the currant shade than that one.

Comment: [Please test design / colour changes in dark mode and site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381873/please-test-design-colour-changes-in-dark-mode-and-site-themes)

Comment: For whoever want to close the question: I thought on Meta a _**discussion**_ means that you can give an opinion about how the site looks and make suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having site-unique colors for this part of the design isn't an option, since having "[unified site designs](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11693/191178)" makes it easier to maintain and update the network. However, you can vote on the [various MSE proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381864/323179) to show your interest in possible alternatives. No guarantees, but the more interest there is, the more likely something will be changed.

Just look at these mock-ups!

[image: Favorite question with green-background checkmark only, desktop]

[image: question with green-600 background checkmark only, mobile]

(And [look who made them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381871/323179) — what a coincidence!)